# Why JQuery.getJson executed after my loop?

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I want my data to be sorted
as i can see the pokeparser function gives a url every time but getJson is executed after the end of the loop, how can it be done at the same time?

```
let counter = 151;
for(let i = 1; i <= counter; i++){
    let url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/`;
    url = url + i;
    //console.log(url);
    poke_parser(url);    
}
  
function poke_parser(url){
    console.log("before  "+ url); ///////////////////////////////in that time i is taxionomicly
                                  ///////when the loop finished go to get Json 
    jQuery.getJSON(url,function(data){
        console.log("after  "+ url); 
        //////////////////////////instead executed after the loop 
        ////////// What can i do?
        // .......................
    });
}
```

Comment: This is because `getJSON` is asynchronous and by the time the first response comes back the loop is already over. What is your intention? to process them one by one?

Comment: Consider `getJSON` as "go away and get this"..."while I carry on what I was doing" - the *callback* `function(data){..` is what to do when it's "got it" - ie "go and get this, when you've got it, do this [callback]" - so whatever code you want to run *after* it has retrieved the json goes in the callback.  If you want to wait until all 151 calls have been made, then you need to return the `promise` that getJSON returns and handle that.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `getJSON` is asynchronous and by the time the first response comes back the loop is already over.

```js
// stub
var jQuery = {
  getJSON: function(url, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      cb({
        something: 12
      })
    }, Math.random() * 1000)
  }
}

let counter = 8;
for (let i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
  let url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/`;
  url = url + i;
  poke_parser(url);
}


function poke_parser(url) {
  console.log("before  " + url);
  jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log("after  " + url);
  });
}
```

But if your intention is to process a response only after the previous has been processed then you can use this technique:

```js
// stub
var jQuery = {
  getJSON: function(url, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      cb({
        something: 12
      })
    }, Math.random() * 1000)
  }
}

let counter = 8;
do_one(1)

function do_one(i) {
  let url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/`;
  url = url + i;
  poke_parser(url, function() {
    if (i < counter) {
      do_one(i + 1)
    }
  });

}

function poke_parser(url, foo_then) {
  console.log("before  " + url);
  jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log("after  " + url);

    if (typeof foo_then === "function") {
      foo_then();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks i need the second way. . . But when i put it in my code does not work

Comment: it's a little tricky but the example is based on your code. of course, the jQuery stub part need to be removed.