# how to execute loop after completion of onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

for each value, i have to trigger onchange event. However, with the current code, onchange event is not triggering for each value.

it works fine with one single array value. However, it is causing issue with multiple values. i think we need to trigger one onchange event at a time. once it is complete, then move to next array value and trigger onchange event again.
my code is:

```
for ( var i=0; i <= getzip.length-1; i++)
     {
           $('span:contains('+getzip[i]+')').parent().parent().find('td:nth-child(4) > Span > input').not('[disabled="disabled"]').attr('checked', true);
           $('span:contains('+getzip[i]+')').parent().parent().find('td:nth-child(4) > Span').trigger('onchange');


     }
```

Thanks,

Tried with above code but it is not giving expected result.

Comment: Please add a jsFiddle Link reproducing the same issue.

Comment: should be `.trigger('change')`

Comment: @IT goldman, it is giving me the same issue with .trigger('change'). my concern is that if a loop is executing, it should wait for onchange request to get completed. On onchange request, an xhr request generated which takes time for an execution

Comment: yes it's not a solution just a comment. if you want to trigger `change` on a one by one basis, waiting for previous call to complete then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74761290/3807365) might help